# Get all Guid in javascript crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-2013

I need to get all guids in an Entity by using Javascript crm 2011?for Ex:I have the Entity called Contact.In that contact Entity ther is an 5000 records.I need to get alll 5000 guid in a Javacript .

How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

**OData** is limited to 50 records. To Retrive more than 50 records we have to use **Paging**
kindly check this [RetrieveRecords](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crminthefield/archive/2012/03/16/how-to-increase-the-50-record-page-limit-on-odata-retrieve-responses-for-dynamics-crm-2011.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For a "bulk Get" you can try [This solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crminthefield/archive/2011/08/04/displaying-the-guid-of-the-record-selected-using-the-lt-crmparameter-gt-parameter.aspx)

To get just one guid, you can use **Web Resources**(Simple HTML page).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function RetreiveGuid() 
{
    var guid = window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
    var cleanGuid =guid.replace(/{/g,"").replace(/}/g,"");
    var entityName = window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.getEntityName();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = entityName + " : " + cleanGuid;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<h4>Using Web Resources to Get Guid</h4>

<p id="demo"></p>

<button type="button" onclick="RetreiveGuid()">Get Guid</button>

</body>
</html>
```